# DBIx::Class get the dbh

Tags: database, perl, catalyst, dbix-class

I'm using [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx::Class) in a [Catalyst](http://www.catalystframework.org) app I am building. It works great, but sometimes I need to use my own db functions that I've developed that are very specific to my needs. Because of this, I need a dbh. However, since I'm already using `DBIx::Class` I know that it already has a dbh that it is using. To avoid making another unnecessary connection to the database, I would like to just use the dbh that `DBIx::Class` has already created. I know that the [DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx::Class::Storage::DBI#dbh_do) module has two methods `dbh` and `dbh_do`, but I'm not really sure what the difference is between the two and if they are the best way to get access to the dbh. Can anyone tell me what the best way to get the dbh from `DBIx::Class` would be in a `Catalyst` app? I'd prefer a method that I could forward to that would store the dbh in the stash like below:

```
sub dbh :Private { 
    my ($self, $c) = @_;
    $c->stash->{dbh} = #get dbh from DBIx::Class here
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I always have to look this up. Assuming you have an instance of your schema object, you can get its Storage object via the `storage` method. Assuming that's a [`Storage::DBI`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aStorage%3a%3aDBI), then there is a [`dbh`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aStorage%3a%3aDBI#dbh) method available which will get you your database handle. So:

```
my $dbh = $c->model( 'My::DB' )->storage->dbh;
```

should do the trick.

Comment: And is there any reason to use `dbh_do` instead? Because the documentation for `dbh` says: `Consider using "dbh_do" instead.`.

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but the docs for `dbh_do` say that is uses a new exception system. (I guess by wrapping `$dbh->do` and executing the supplied function.) So I guess that's why. I've never had any problems just using the raw `$dbh`, though.

Comment: @srchulo yes, anything you run under `dbh_do` will be subject to the DBIx::Class connection management (reconnecting if the DB connection is lost). There's also `txn_do` for very nice transaction management.

Comment: @hobbs, so `dbh` is not subject to the DBIx::Class connection management? i.e., it won't reconnect if the connection is lost?

Comment: @srchulo `->dbh` will reconnect if the connection is down at the moment you call `->dbh`, but it can't do anything about a connection that's lost later on while you're using the handle it gave you.

Comment: @hobbs, okay. that makes sense now. thanks for explaining the difference.

Answer (score -2):

@srchulo Answers are great and dbh_do is way to go for it's inbuilt exception handling but I will advice to convert your function to rather not use dbh anymore and just work with DBIX::Class. That way, next time, you just have to change at one place and not keep looking for legacy dbh and raw sqls. Hope it makes sense.